# Word matching in ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

This is how I'm mapping my index.

```
 settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
              .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
              .MapDefaultTypeNames(m => m.Add(typeof(MyClass), "content"))
              .PrettyJson()
              .DisableDirectStreaming());
```

Lets say I have a document indexed to ES with

> content: "Tim Cook revealed during the earnings call that iPhone sales
>   in India grew by 56% on a yearly basis, despite the company's first
>   global sales decline in 13 years."

Now if a user searches for a word using a match query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "answer": {
        "query": "decline"
      }
    }
}}
```

say i get a score of 0.047.

But with the same query, if I search for the word ***"declining"***, I get a score of 0. I want to check if the word is partially present in the document or not. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your field mapping by declaring a specific analyzer to analyze your content field. In this case, we could use the [`english` language analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lang-analyzer.html#english-analyzer) which will stem the tokens according to english grammatic and lexical rules.

```
PUT your_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "your_type": {
      "properties": {
        "content": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can index your content

```
PUT /your_index/your_type/1
{
  "content": "Tim Cook revealed during the earnings call that iPhone sales in India grew by 56% on a yearly basis, despite the company's first global sales decline in 13 years."
}
```

And finally you can search both `decline` and `declining` and get the same score

```
POST /your_index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": {
        "query": "decline"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /your_index/_search 
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "content": {
        "query": "declining"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But is it possible to change the existing mapping. because I already have the application running. How can i change the mapping to the one you mentioned above?

Comment: Changing mapping is not possible. You can delete your existing index and recreate it with the mapping I gave. Then you need to re-index your data, i.e. repopulate your index.

Comment: Thanks val. Can you help me in modifying the mapping using LINQ with the analyzer type. I have updated my index mapping in the question. TIA :)

Comment: I'm not LINQ-savvy, unfortunately, not sure how to help there.

Comment: Did this help at all?

Comment: It still showing a score of '0' even after changing the mapping to what you have said.

Comment: You've created a new index with new data?

Comment: Can you show what you get from running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your_index` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110457/discussion-between-asn-and-val).